# How to catch selected value from Radio button in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, dynamic-data, angular-ngmodel

Hello every one i'm trying to make a MCQ question from for that I'm trying to catch selected value from Radio button in AngularJS. Main problem i'm facing that i'm binding data from database and those are dynamic. So i have to use ng-repeat from loading those questions in view HTML, so i can't manually handle the  "ng-model" for those options. when click the submit button i need catch the question with the answer  like [{QuestionId:1:AnswerId:4}, {QuestionId:1:AnswerId:3}...] or something like that. Here I've made a JSON data for previewing the scenario. Hope it'll help all to understand my problem and may solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

View code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c15mj8pf/5/)

Here is the HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="testController">
   <form>
    <div ng-repeat="qus in QusWithOptions">
        <td>{{qus.id}}. {{qus.Question}} </td><br />               
<input type="radio" name="taskGroup{{qus.id}}" ng-model="asd" value="{{qus.OptionA_KPI}}" />{{qus.OptionA}}
<input type="radio" name="taskGroup{{qus.id}}" ng-model="asd" value="{{qus.OptionB_KPI}}" />{{qus.OptionB}}
<input type="radio" name="taskGroup{{qus.id}}" ng-model="asd" value="{{qus.OptionC_KPI}}" />{{qus.OptionC}}
<input type="radio" name="taskGroup{{qus.id}}" ng-model="asd" value="{{qus.OptionD_KPI}}" />{{qus.OptionD}}
         </div>
    <button ng-click="SaveAnswer(asd)">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is Js file

```
    var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);

    function testController($scope){
    $scope.QusWithOptions = [
        {id:1, Question: "What is best social network site?", OptionA: "facebook", OptionB: "twitter", OptionC: "google+", OptionD: "others",OptionA_KPI:1,OptionB_KPI:2,OptionC_KPI:3,OptionD_KPI:4  },
        {id:2, Question: "Entomology is the science that studies ?", OptionA: "Behavior of human beings", OptionB: "Insects", OptionC: "Origin of scientific terms", OptionD: "The formation of rocks", OptionA_KPI:1,OptionB_KPI:2,OptionC_KPI:3,OptionD_KPI:4 },
        {id:3, Question: "Eritrea, which became the 182nd member of the UN in 1993, is in the continent of ?", OptionA: "Asia", OptionB: "Europe", OptionC: "Australia", OptionD: "Europe", OptionA_KPI:1,OptionB_KPI:2,OptionC_KPI:3,OptionD_KPI:4},
        {id:4, Question: "For the Olympics and World Tournaments, the dimensions of basketball court are ?", OptionA: "26 m x 14 m", OptionB: "28 m x 15 m", OptionC: "27 m x 16 m", OptionD: "28 m x 16 m",OptionA_KPI:1,OptionB_KPI:2,OptionC_KPI:3,OptionD_KPI:4 },];

    $scope.SaveAnswer = function(){
         window.alert();
    };
}
```

Comment: If i select option D, then what you want? Is `OptionD_KPI` value or `OptionD` value?

Comment: i want OptionD_KPI in this case.

Comment: With the id (like question Id). Is am correct? 

the result look like `[{QuestionId:1:AnswerId:4},{QuestionId:1:AnswerId:3}...]` ?

Comment: yes....absolutely, i want it in that format.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `ng-model` `asd[$index]` instead of `asd` only, You could have something like this

```
<div ng-controller="testController">
    <form>
        <div ng-repeat="qus in QusWithOptions">
            <td>{{qus.id}}. {{qus.Question}} </td>
            <br />

            <input type="radio" name="taskGroup{{qus.id}}" ng-model="asd[$index]" value="{{qus.OptionA_KPI}}" />{{qus.OptionA}}
            <input type="radio" name="taskGroup{{qus.id}}" ng-model="asd[$index]" value="{{qus.OptionB_KPI}}" />{{qus.OptionB}}
            <input type="radio" name="taskGroup{{qus.id}}" ng-model="asd[$index]" value="{{qus.OptionC_KPI}}" />{{qus.OptionC}}
            <input type="radio" name="taskGroup{{qus.id}}" ng-model="asd[$index]" value="{{qus.OptionD_KPI}}" />{{qus.OptionD}}
        </div>
        {{asd}}
        <button ng-click="SaveAnswer(asd)">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you want question & answer combination, you could do something like do maintain one object `$scope.asd = {}` in that you would have key value pair of question & answer, like `["1": "2", "2":"3"]` which does mean that question 1 has answer 2 & question 2 has selected answer 3.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c15mj8pf/9/)

Comment: Please read the OP question clearly `Moreover after submitting the answer i need catch the question with the answer.`. The OP want the **question and answer** when click the submit button.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I updated my answer..please take a look at it & remove the downvote please

Comment: i didn't down voted you, and i can't even vote(for below point).

Comment: still not good, now he needs  the result should be `[{QuestionId:1:AnswerId:4}, {QuestionId:1:AnswerId:3}...] ` But any way. it's nice effort. i removed the down vote

Comment: @RameshRajendran Thanks for removing downvote..:) I think you have proposed it..let me look at that too..